# Get GDB backtrace of core file through PHP

Tags: php, gdb

I'm trying to get a GDB backtrace output from GDB through PHP.  I'd like to use system() to call "gdb /path/to/application /path/to/corefile", but then I need to run "backtrace" within GDB.

Is there a way to execute a program through PHP and then run a command in that program while it's running?  I'm open to other ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried it, but you could use tty functionality for this.

gdb has a -tty parameter that accepts input to standard input - so the tricky part is getting PHP to write. Someone in the PHP manual has contributed a function that may do what you need: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.readline.php#38022

Sorry if it's not right, but given the absence of any other answers, this is what I'd be trying.

---

Edit: another thought. proc_open should do what you want: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php